# Full Text Search searching issue

Tags: sql-server-2005, search, full-text-search

the reason I'm here is SQL 2005 fulltext search.

I'm searching with this query here:

```
declare @SearchText nvarchar(1000)
set @SearchText='Dream';

SELECT  *         
 FROM              
  MashupSearchLookup AS FT_MyTable   WITH (NOLOCK)             
  INNER JOIN FREETEXTTABLE(MyTable, *, @SearchText ) AS KEY_TBL           
  ON FT_MyTable.ID = KEY_TBL.[KEY]
```

When I search `football` then it shows 3 rows which is fine, but when I search for `foot` or `ball` then no records are returned. For me it is searching like matching exact case.

Is there anything I can do to get results for `foot` and `ball`, too ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To search for the words staring with `foot`, use:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    MashupSearchLookup
WHERE   CONTAINS(*, '"foot*"')
```

In `SQL Server`, `FULLTEXT` queries cannot match suffixes or infixes (that is you cannot search for `"*ball"` or `"*otba*"`).

The best you can do to search for this is using `LIKE`:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    MashupSearchLookup
WHERE   col1 LIKE '%ball%'
        OR col2 LIKE '%ball%'
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks for reply, i have two question now, what if user enters "foot ball" then do i have to pass this like foot OR ball?? second thing is that m using RANK thats why i m using FREETEXTTABLE

Comment: @user: query for `'"foot" OR "ball"'` (or `'"foot*" OR "ball*"'` in you want to match prefixes). If you need `RANK` you can use `CONTAINSTABLE` instead of `CONTAINS`.